# why the use of ' much of which ' in the following sentence is incorrect?

Tags: grammar

Electronic games, much of which can be powerful instructional tools, are becoming more and more prevalent with the proliferation of computers in schools.

Comment: What has your dictionary search revealed?

Comment: I couldn't find an answer for my question, much of which is incorrect but i don't know the reason

Comment: https://grammarist.com/usage/many-much/

Answer (score 3):

It is not normal because the antecedent of "which" is "games", which is plural; so selecting from them requires the countable term "many", rather than the uncountable "much".

So, "many of which" would be more normal.